# suppress printing axis label in metpy

Tags: matplotlib, metpy

I am generating SkewT plots using MetPy. I am trying to suppress the automatic generation of axis labels and use my own. The automatic labels generated are hectopascal and degree_Celsius.I can't find a way to disable the automatic axis labels so the end result is a messy looking plot. The unwanted auto-generated labels are circled in muddy red:

[image: Plot with unwanted extra labels]

I tried turning them off by adding

```
plt.axis('off')
```

but not only did it remove the labels it removed the tick marks and everything, even the border around the plot.

I tried getting more creative with

```
plt.gca().axes.yaxis.set_label([])
```

or

```
skew.ax.xaxis.set_label([])
```

but neither of these worked. Other things I tried for removing the labels also removed the tick values.

I know I'm probably missing something simple but I can't seem to locate it.

Here's a sample code that demonstrates this using a slightly modified SkewT plot example from MetPy:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import metpy.calc as mpcalc
from metpy.plots import SkewT
from metpy.units import units

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9, 9))
skew = SkewT(fig, rotation=45)

# Create arrays of pressure, temperature, dewpoint, and wind components
p = [902, 897, 893, 889, 883, 874, 866, 857, 849, 841, 833, 824, 812, 796, 776, 751,
     727, 704, 680, 656, 629, 597, 565, 533, 501, 468, 435, 401, 366, 331, 295, 258,
     220, 182, 144, 106] * units.hPa
t = [-3, -3.7, -4.1, -4.5, -5.1, -5.8, -6.5, -7.2, -7.9, -8.6, -8.9, -7.6, -6, -5.1,
     -5.2, -5.6, -5.4, -4.9, -5.2, -6.3, -8.4, -11.5, -14.9, -18.4, -21.9, -25.4,
     -28, -32, -37, -43, -49, -54, -56, -57, -58, -60] * units.degC
td = [-22, -22.1, -22.2, -22.3, -22.4, -22.5, -22.6, -22.7, -22.8, -22.9, -22.4,
      -21.6, -21.6, -21.9, -23.6, -27.1, -31, -38, -44, -46, -43, -37, -34, -36,
      -42, -46, -49, -48, -47, -49, -55, -63, -72, -88, -93, -92] * units.degC

# Calculate parcel profile
prof = mpcalc.parcel_profile(p, t[0], td[0]).to('degC')
u = np.linspace(-10, 10, len(p)) * units.knots
v = np.linspace(-20, 20, len(p)) * units.knots

skew.plot(p, t, 'r', linewidth=4)
skew.plot(p, td, 'g', linewidth=4)
skew.plot(p, prof, 'k', linewidth=3)  # Plot parcel profile
skew.plot_barbs(p[::5], u[::5], v[::5])

skew.ax.set_xlim(-50, 30)
skew.ax.set_ylim(1000, 150)
skew.ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(which='major', labelsize=15, direction='out')
skew.ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(which='major', labelsize=15, direction='out')

#THIS DIDN'T WORK
#skew.ax.xaxis.set_label([])  

# Add the relevant special lines
skew.plot_dry_adiabats()
skew.plot_moist_adiabats()
skew.plot_mixing_lines()

# Labels
fig.text(0.52,0.05, "temperature ($^{o}$C)", ha="center", va="center", fontsize=18)
fig.text(0.04,0.5, "pressure (hPa)", ha="center", va="center", rotation=90, fontsize=18)

plt.show()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the functions you're looking for are `set_xlabel` or `set_ylabel`:

```
# Clear out the default labels
skew.ax.set_xlabel('')
skew.ax.set_ylabel('')
```

If you *really* want to use the methods on `.xaxis` and `.yaxis`, it would be:

```
skew.ax.xaxis.set_label_text('')
skew.ax.yaxis.set_label_text('')
```

I wanted to also point out that you don't just have to clear out the labels, but you should be able to use those methods to achieve what you're doing with `fig.text`:

```
# Use \N for named unicode character
skew.ax.set_xlabel('temperature (\N{DEGREE CELSIUS})',
                   fontdict=dict(size=18))
skew.ax.set_ylabel('pressure (hPa)', fontdict=dict(size=18))
```